# How to duck type a method in F# with multiple arguments?

Tags: f#, duck-typing

```
/// Sets a dependency property
let inline setDP (prop: DependencyProperty) (v: obj) (target: ^a when ^a: (member SetValue: DependencyProperty * obj -> unit)) =
    ( ^a : (member SetValue: DependencyProperty * obj -> unit) (prop,v))
    target
```

I cannot figure out how to do duck typing for anything except the simplest types. Here I get the error `Expected 3 expressions, got 2`. I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
/// Sets a dependency property
let inline setDP (prop: DependencyProperty) (v: obj) (target: ^a when ^a: (member SetValue: DependencyProperty * obj -> unit)) =
    ( ^a : (member SetValue: DependencyProperty * obj -> unit) (target,prop,v))
    target
```

I amazed how funky the syntax for this is. This and struct syntax are definitely two of F#'s weak spots.

Comment: Note that you don't need to specify the (duck) types in the method signature. The compiler will figure that out for you.